# HEAP Space issue with Non-partitioned tables in ADLA

Tags: azure, optimization, partitioning, azure-table-storage, azure-data-lake

I am pretty new to the Data Engineering world and would want to understand how to tackle the HEAP space issue for non partitioned tables in Azure Data Lake.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Data Lake (ADL) is a data storage service and there is no such concept of HEAP Space in it. You can use Azure services like Azure Data Factory, Logic Apps, Azure Databricks, etc. to ingest data, perform analytics, and create visual representations with ADL.

To perform data ingestion, perform analytics, etc. with ADL, you need some compute infrastructure(memory, CPU cores, etc). For example, if you are ingesting data from ADL to Azure SQL Database, you need Azure Integration Runtime (IR) which provides compute infrastructure to perform the task. You can change the compute type and core count of your Azure Integration Runtime depend on the volume of data and number of pipelines you are running using the assigned Azure IR(if facing lag in the performance). You can also set how many data integration units to use on the copy activity, and the compute size of the Azure IR is elastically scaled up accordingly without you having to explicitly adjusting size of the Azure Integration Runtime.

I suggest you to go through the official Azure Data lake documents and the services which can integrate with it. Generally, since all these services are PaaS, therefore all the memory management, scaling and other things are managed by the Azure itself.

Useful links: [azure data lake performance guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-performance-tuning-guidance), [azure data lake supported azure service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-supported-azure-services)